# Pause video before every loop

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I have a video element that I want to pause for 3 seconds before each loop.  The purpose is to show the poster image/attribute during those pauses.  I've got it set up to do this before the initial play, but how do I get it do pause before each loop?

In addition, I have some header elements that are hidden during these pauses, but are shown again when the video resumes.  I don't think this part should interfere, but wanted to note it. Both header and subheader elements have the class 'hide' on them.

Markup

```
<video id="video" 
    poster="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/img/award.jpg" playsinline 
    muted loop>
    <source type="video/mp4" src="<?php the_field('hero_video'); ?>" />
</video>
```

CSS

```
.hide {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .2s ease;
}
```

Javascript

```
let video = document.getElementById("video");
    let heading = document.querySelector(".hero-heading");
    let subheading = document.querySelector(".hero-subheading")
    
    video.addEventListener("canplay", function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            video.play();
            heading.classList.remove('hide');
            subheading.classList.remove('hide');
        }, 3000);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Got here from Google, was looking to do this and ended up figuring it out. Posting here in case anyone else comes across this.

Instead of setTimeout in there, use the video `ended` event.

```
let video = document.querySelector("video");
let heading = document.querySelector(".hero-heading");
let subheading = document.querySelector(".hero-subheading");

video.addEventListener("ended", async (event) => {

    heading.classList.add('hide');
    subheading.classList.add('hide');

    // Does the equivalent of a sleep in JS
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));

    heading.classList.remove('hide');
    subheading.classList.remove('hide');

    // start playing the video again
    video.play();
});
```